# Open source to generate HTML page with T4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, t4

Is there any open source .NET project that uses T4 to generate HTML page or HTML content?

I need to build a web reporting tool that reads MS SQL schema and generates pages that show data from DB.

Comment: Have you tried? What roadblocks are you experiencing?